# Avoiding loitering when implementing generic data structure in C#

Tags: c#, generics

Suppose that I have a data structure (let's say a stack) that uses an array to store the elements.

Something like this

```
class Stack<T>
{
    private T[] _items;
    int Size {get; set; }
    // irrelevant code
    
    T pop()
    {
         // Some condition checking
         --Size;
         T result = _items[Size];
         _items[Size] = null;         // Needed if T is a reference type and we want to reclaim the                    
                                      // memory, however will not 
                                      // compile, since T is not necessarily a reference type
        
         return result;
     }
     // Irrelevant
 }
```

My question, whether it is possible to make _items[Size] = null, conditional, depending on the type of T. If yes, how is it done?

Comment: i guess you want that cause you can't apply `null` to structs and you don't have a generic constraint on T, in that case i'd try to set it to `default`

Comment: maybe `_items[Size] = default`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
_items[Size] = default(T);
```

Should work for all types, whether it's reference or value types.

Comment: C# 7.1, you can use `default`. Save your self 3 characters!

Comment: That's true, but I don't know if the OP is using 7.1 or higher.

Comment: I was wondering whether it is possible to do it if I want my code to be null safe. if T is a reference, then _items[Size] = default will be null. If I treat warnings as errors and CS8601, then the code will not compile. What would be the work around in this case?